# How to delete rows with more than a certain threshold of cells empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks something like this:

```
       product                                   book_title  ...                                genres genres_names
0        63328                                          NaN  ...                                   NaN          NaN
1        63329                                          NaN  ...                                   NaN          NaN
2        63330                                          NaN  ...                                   NaN          NaN
3        63721                   Testigo de la misericordia  ...  HRCC7,HRCM,HRCX1,REL010000,REL067000          NaN
4        63722                             Caminos del alma  ...                          SEL000000,VS          NaN
```

As you can see the first two elements have almost every field empty except the product field, I would like to erase them from the Dataframe to perform certain computations without them causing noise.

How can I drop certain rows depending on the number of empty cells they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dropna, threshold so that you keep only the rows with at least `n` non NaN, assuming none of the other rows have more than 1 non NaN, you can

```
 df.dropna(thresh=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This solution seemed right but it isn't working, I don't know why.

Comment: Add inplace=True, so that it gets registered

Comment: Happy it did for you

Comment: Okay, I have the problem again, I thought I could use the threshold to change it and just drop those rows with 3 or more empty cells but that didn't work (it work in my small test case because it didn't have a lot of NaN there) but in the whole data-frame it erases almost everything because there are other rows with NaN but that shouldn't be deleted

Comment: Unless we have more detail it is hard to say. The method should work regardless of the dataframe. Give more info about the dateset maybe

Comment: As you can see in the example Data-frame I provided almost all items have genres_names set as NaN, that's where my problem lays as If I make dropna(thresh=1) it will erase all the rows with that cell set as NaN too even though I want to keep them, I just want to delete the rows with more than 3 cells set as NaN, that would mean that those rows are not providing any relevant information

Comment: If you look at my answer I stated at least n NaN. n can be any number. in this case, I used 1 as an example. make it df.dropna(thresh=2, inplace=True) if all you need is more than 3

Comment: Okay, I've finally understood your answer: Thresh indicates the minimum number of non-NaN values, so I have to indicate the minimum number of cells that should have content, not the minimum number of cells to consider empty. Sorry!

Comment: Me bad, it is non-NA values.Accept answer if ok